# ASP MVC - create json structure

Tags: c#, json

i have a problem. I would like create this json structure in ASP Controller:

```
{
"title": "T1",
"data": [
    { "value": "v1", "key": "k1" },
    { "value": "v2",       "key": "k2" }
]
}
```

I tried this:

```
var data = new
        {
            title = "T1",
            data = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    value = "V1",
                    key= "K1"
                },
                new
                {
                    value = "V2",
                    key= "K2"
                }
            }
        };
```

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Json method in your controller's action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetJsonData()
    {
        var data = new
        {
            title = "T1",
            data = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    value = "V1",
                    key = "K1"
                },
                new
                {
                    value = "V2",
                    key = "K2"
                }
            }
        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I use Json method, of course. But I dont get this structure.

Comment: @bluray What structure do you get?

Comment: I need this structure     {
"title": "T1",
"data": [
    { "value": "v1", "key": "k1" },
    { "value": "v2",       "key": "k2" }
]
}

Comment: @bluray I get the structure that you need with code which I provided (here the output of my browser http://prnt.sc/auwzxd). What version of ASP.NET MVC do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either **JsonConvert.SerializeObject()** method from Newtonsoft.Json package to convert your data object to string in json format:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) like:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.FromObject(data);
var json = jsonObject.ToString();
```

Where `data` is your anonymous object you posted above.
Json.Net can be downloaded via Nuget as `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

(If it's a controller action you can just return `Json(data)`)